# Use Raspberry Pi to Remotely Control KVM by emulating Keyboard

Tags: linux, usb, keyboard, kvm-switch, hid

I have a KVM located far away from me that I would like to control with a Streamdeck. The problem is that the KVM only supports changing inputs in the following ways:

- Physical buttons on the device
- IR Remote Control
- Keyboard Hotkeys

[This is the user manual](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0271/3429/6200/files/HKS0403A1U_Manual_e502566b-f2a3-4281-813b-7a48917fc581.pdf?v=1681203533) of the KVM in question. See page 36.

The keyboard hotkeys option stands out to me, because essentially if I could program a keyboard to send these keystrokes automatically, I could have the Streamdeck run a script which contacts the keyboard (over IP) to send a particular sequence of keystrokes.

Here's an example hotkey:

[image]

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 that I think would be able to do this. I could plug the Pi via its ethernet port into the same network switch that the Windows computer running the Streamdeck is plugged into, so the Windows computer could send commands to the Raspberry Pi. The Pi could be listening for commands, and then when it gets one, send the desired keystrokes to the KVM through a USB-A to USB-A cable.

I don't know if this will work since the KVM has dedicated mouse/keyboard USB ports that do not function properly with other USB devices. If this is possible, I somehow have to trick the KVM into thinking the Pi truly is a keyboard. This is a note from the manual:

> The keyboard hot keys can only work with external keyboard correctly
> connected to the **keyboard and mouse input port** of the KVM.

These are the ports in reference:

[image]

I think the issue I will run into here is that, even if I can turn the Pi into a keyboard, attempting to send the hotkey shortcuts to the KVM won't work since I have to use those special USB ports highlighted in red.

**Is this possible? Or will the KVM not be able to detect the hotkey keystrokes through those special USB ports since the Pi isn't a real keyboard?**

Comment: you could try it but you could also hack the IR remote or the pushbuttons. I don't know if a Pi can emulate a keyboard or anything else or even be a USB device (plug into a USB A port) at all? I've never heard of it being able to do that?

Comment: @user253751, what do you mean by hack the IR remote or pushbuttons? Do you have an example? I'm not sure how I would do that.

Comment: IIRC the Pi 3 can not be used in so called "gadget" mode. Pi Zero can (but has no ethernet of course) and Pi 4 apparently can. I guess you could attach a USB->Ethernet device on to the Pi Zero

Comment: @jippyjoe4 take the thing apart, put relays in parallel with the push buttons, use the raspberry pi to trigger the relay. (smaller circuits may be possible depending on how the pushbuttons are wired, but a relay is a universal solution that works no matter how they are wired). Or, put an IR transmitter on the pi, and make it send the same code the remote sends when you press the buttons on the remote (you'll need to measure these, maybe with an IR receiver on the pi)